Proof of Limit of a Sequence Raised to a Positive Integer Power
Problem statement:
If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n =L$, prove using $\epsilon, N$ definition
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n^p = L^p
\end{align*} Where $p \in \mathbb{N}$
Solution:
We need to show that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$
\begin{align*}
|a_n^p-L^p| < \epsilon
\end{align*}
observations:
Using the identity
\begin{align*}
x^p-y^p = (x-y)(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}y+...+xy^{p-2}+y^{p-1})
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
 |a_n^p -L^p| = |a_n-L||a_n^{p-1}+a_n^{p-2}L+...+a_nL^{p-2}+L^{p-1}|\\
\implies |a_n^p -L^p| \leq |a_n-L|||a_n^{p-1}|+|a_n^{p-2}L|+...+|a_nL^{p-2}|+|L^{p-1}||
\end{align*}
We need to bound $|a_n^kL^m|$ where $k,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq k,m \leq p-1$ with $k+m =p-1$.
\begin{align*}
|a_n-L| <1 &\implies -1 < a_n-L<1 \implies L-1<a_n<L+1\\
&\implies |a_n| < |L|+1 \qquad \text{ for some } n > N_1\\
&\implies |a_n|^k |L|^m <(|L|+1)^k|L|^m
\end{align*}
Now, if $n > N_1$
\begin{align}
|a_n^p -L^p| < |a_n-L|\left((|L|+1)^{p-1}+(|L|+1)^{p-2}|L|+...+(|L|+1)|L|^{p-2}+|L|^{p-1} \right) \qquad (*)
\end{align}
Hence we bound $|a_n^p-L^p|$ above by $\epsilon$ by requiring that:
\begin{align*}
|a_n-L| < \frac{\epsilon}{\left((|L|+1)^{p-1}+(|L|+1)^{p-2}|L|+...+(|L|+1)|L|^{p-2}+|L|^{p-1} \right)}
\end{align*}
for some $p \in \mathbb{N}$.
proof:
Now, we can complete the proof. Because $a_n \to L$, $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N_0$ then for $\epsilon_0 = 1$,
\begin{align*}
|a_n-L| <1 &\implies |a_n| < |L|+1 \\
&\implies |a_n|^k |L|^m <(|L|+1)^k|L|^m
\end{align*}
For $k,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq k,m \leq p-1$ with $k+m =p-1$.
Again, using the fact that $a_n \to L$, $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$  such that if $n > N_1$ then for $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and some $\epsilon_1$,
\begin{align*}
|a_n-L|  < \epsilon_1 = \frac{\epsilon}{\left((|L|+1)^{p-1}+(|L|+1)^{p-2}|L|+...+(|L|+1)|L|^{p-2}+|L|^{p-1} \right)}
\end{align*}
Then, for any arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N = max\{N_0, N_1\}$ such that if $n > N$, both the previous inequalities hold:
\begin{align*}
|a_n^p -L^p| = |a_n-L||a_n^{p-1}+a_n^{p-2}L+...+a_nL^{p-2}+L^{p-1}| \\
\implies |a_n^p -L^p| \leq |a_n-L|\left||a_n^{p-1}|+|a_n^{p-2}L|+...+|a_nL^{p-2}|+|L^{p-1}|\right|\\
\implies |a_n^p -L^p| < |a_n-L|\left((|L|+1)^{p-1}+(|L|+1)^{p-2}|L|+...+(|L|+1)|L|^{p-2}+|L|^{p-1} \right)\\ 
\implies |a_n^p -L^p| < \frac{\epsilon}{\left((|L|+1)^{p-1}+...+|L|^{p-1} \right)} * \left((|L|+1)^{p-1}+...+|L|^{p-1} \right) = \epsilon
\end{align*}
Hence, if $a_n\to L$, $a_n^p \to L^p$ for positive sequences of $a_n$ and $p \in \mathbb{N}$
Questions:
I have not found a proof of power of a sequence with limit on the internet. Hence I have a few concerns about the valadity of my proof:

Is the general approach of the proof sound? are there any flaws in the general argument?
Is the specific expression marked $(*)$ sound?
Is the argument using $N_0$, $N_1$, $\epsilon_1$ technically correct?

Would be interested in also getting more elegant $\epsilon, N$ proofs for this problem.
Edit: Removed redundant step

Think I could have simplified the $(|L|+1)^k|L|^m$ argument by letting $M = max{ (|L|+1)^k|L|^m}$ then use $pM$ instead of using $\left((|L|+1)^{p-1}+(|L|+1)^{p-2}|L|+...+(|L|+1)|L|^{p-2}+|L|^{p-1} \right)$

I think $()$ is just fine. You solution could be simplified, if you also replaced the $|L|$ by $|L|+1$. Then  $()$ would become $|a_n^p-L^p|\leq |a_n - L|,p (|L|+1)^{p-1}$.

That would also work. Shame I can't find a more elegant $\epsilon$, $N$ proof or any other proof for this

I wrote up what I had in mind for an $\varepsilon, N$ proof. It is essentially the same as your proof.
A proof using that the power function $f(x) = x^p$ is continuous would shorter, if you ignore the proof that the power function is continuous. You could also give a proof using the limit of a product is the product of the limits and induction to establish the claim, that would probably be about the same length as the proof below.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.
Since $a_{n}\to L$ there is an $N_{1}$ such that $n>N_{1}\implies \left|a_{n}\right|\leq \left|a_{n}-L\right|+\left|L\right|<1+\left|L\right|.$
If $\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\leq M,$ then
$$
\left|x^{p}-y^{p}\right|=\left|x-y\right|\left|\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}x^{k}y^{p-1-k}\right|\leq\left|x-y\right|pM^{p-1}
$$
Replacing $x$ with $a_{n},$ $y$ with $L,$ and $M$
with $1+\left|L\right|$ we have,
$$
\left|a_{n}^{p}-L^{p}\right|\leq\left|a_{n}-L\right|p\left(1+\left|L\right|\right)^{p-1}\text{ when }n>N_{1}.
$$
Let $N_{2}$ be such that $n>N_{2}\implies\left|a_{n}-L\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{p\left(1+\left|L\right|\right)^{p-1}}.$
Then  $n>\max\{N_{1},N_{2}\} \implies \left|a_{n}^{p}-L^{p}\right|<\varepsilon.$
